# How to fix "variable not initialized" error in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I am trying to make a program called blin-maker (or you can call blins as pancakes) which calculates how much blins I can make.

```
if (eggsAmount < eggsMin || milkAmount < milkMin || flourAmount < flourMin) {
    println("No blin today :(")
```

Above is the code which is giving me the error. I want to calculate if the eggs, milk and flour are lower the minimum amount (See variable eggsMIn, milkMin, and flourMin).

But its not letting me run the code due to the error:

```
Kotlin: Variable 'eggsAmount' must be initialized.
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hopefully the existing answers help, but please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

give the default value when you defined the var.
such as:

```
var milkAmount :Int=0
```

Comment: you can have more practice on https://kotlinlang.org/

Answer (score 0):

Try typing,

```
 var eggsAmount = 0
```

above,

```
if (eggsAmount < eggsMin || milkAmount < milkMin || flourAmount < flourMin) {
    println("No blin today :(")
```

like,

```
var eggsAmount = 0
if (eggsAmount < eggsMin || milkAmount < milkMin || flourAmount < flourMin) {
    println("No blin today :(")
```